# How to rearrange array of objects to new array of Objects

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects with the same keys, example:

```
const data = [{name: "firstName", value: "John"},
{name: "lastName", value: "Smith"},
{name: "Number", value: "421-8686"}
]
```

I however want the values to become the key and values. example:

```
const data = [{"firstName": "John"},
{"lastName": "Smith"},
{"Number": "421-8686"}]
```

I tried a few methods, but for some reason or another I fail. My latest attempt is:

```
   let newData = {}
    arrayData.forEach((item, index) => {
      let key = data.name
      let value = data.value
      newData[index] = { key: value} // this results in {"key": "John"} --> but i want {"firstName": "John"}
```

});

Comment: `{ [key]: value} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
let data = [
  {name: "firstName", value: "John"},
  {name: "lastName", value: "Smith"},
  {name: "Number", value: "421-8686"}
]

data = data.map(info => Object.fromEntries([[info.name, info.value]]))

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = [{name: "firstName", value: "John"},
{name: "lastName", value: "Smith"},
{name: "Number", value: "421-8686"}
]


/*const data = [{"firstName": "John"},
{"lastName": "Smith"},
{"Number": "421-8686"}]
*/
for(let i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
   
    data[i][data[i].name] = data[i].value  // creates new key value pair
    delete data[i].name                    // deletes old key
    delete data[i].value
    }
    

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    let data = [
       { name: "firstName", value: "John" },
       { name: "lastName", value: "Smith" },
       { name: "Number", value: "421-8686" },
    ];

    // map the data to required format.

    data = data.map((d) => {
       let o = {};
       o[d["name"]] = d["value"];
       return o;
    });
    
    console.log("data",data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should get result as following, what you want.
Of course, I confirmed status.

```
const data = [{name: "firstName", value: "John"},
{name: "lastName", value: "Smith"},
{name: "Number", value: "421-8686"}
]

let newData = [];
data.forEach((item) => {
  let obj = {};
  obj[item.name] = item.value;
  newData.push( obj );
});
    
console.log(newData);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small tweak to your code. Property has to be dynamically created.

In ES6, we can dynamically create a property key by placing the key in square brackets [].

```js
const data = [
  { name: "firstName", value: "John" },
  { name: "lastName", value: "Smith" },
  { name: "Number", value: "421-8686" }
];

let newData = [];
data.forEach((item, index) => newData[index] = {[item.name]: item.value});
console.log(newData)
```